# trim Leading and trailing spaces without using transform stage in datastage

Tags: datastage

I am trying to remove leading and trailing spaces in datastage. In Transform stage we can use TrimLeadingTrailing(ID) to achieve this.  But without using transform stage , i am trying to use Modify stage . Below is the code

```
id = string_trim[" ",begin,end](id)
```

In any of the case by using String_Trim function , only leading or trailing spaces are getting removed.  I am unable to achieve both the things.

Please help if there is any way.

Sample Input :

```
"    Abc  Yyyy    "
```

Sample Output:

```
"Abc  Yyyy"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well look at the [function definition](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZJPZ_11.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.parjob.adref.doc/topics/r_deeadvrf_String_and_Ustring_Field_Conversions.html) this is obvious

```
string_trim[NULL, begin](name)
```

will remove all leading ASCII NULL characters from the beginning of name

```
string_trim['X', end, begin](text)
```

will remove all trailing X chars from text

Becasue of this "direction" you cannot do both at the same time

Comment: Do we have any other way without using transform stage , can we do trim leading trailing. ?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid a transformer stage?

Comment: Actually we have multiple columns and lookups , which ends up using multiple transformers .

Comment: Multiple transformations can also be done in a single transformer in addition to that who said multiple are bad?

Answer (score 0):

There is also the Modify stage, which has four functions for dealing with trimming white space and other characters.  But the Transformer stage has a more intuitive GUI.